# local approximation of a vector field on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, and let $V$ be a $C^{\infty}$ vector field on $M$. Is it possible to locally approximate $V$ by gradient vector fields $\nabla f_i$, such that the $L^{\infty}$-norm 
$$\sup_{B_x(r)}|V-\nabla f_i|\rightarrow 0?$$
for $r$ small enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know the answer if $M$ is just a flat manifold?

Comment: Sorry I don't know...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking the $f_i$ to be smooth then the answer is no, unless $V$ is a gradient (in which case the statement is trivial).

Consider for example the Euclidean space $R^N$, with $B=B_r(0)$ the standard ball centered at the origin. Assume by contradiction that there is such an approximating sequence for smooth $f_i$'s. Then, by simply adding/subtracting constants, you could normalize $f_i(0)=0$. The hypothesis $\nabla f_i\to V$ (which is bounded) implies uniform Lipschitz bounds (write $|\nabla f_i|\leq |V|+|\nabla f_i-V|$), the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem shows that $\{f_i\}_i$ is relatively compact in $C(B)$. Extracting a converging subsequence if needed, you immediately get uniform convergence $f_i\to f$ for some $f\in C(B)$. Since we assumed that the derivatives converge to start with (no extraction needed) we also get $\nabla f_i\to\nabla f=V$.